# How do I parse a JSON file in Python when the file contains non-latin characters and output it as a list of lists?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a json file that looks something like this:

```
{"id": 1, "text": "\"Sathon, Bangkok 10120, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[25, 33, "Country"], [18, 23, "PostCode"], [2, 8, "District"], [10, 17, "Province"]]}
{"id": 2, "text": "\"8/89 ซอยหมู่บ้านหนองแก Tambon Nong Kae, Amphoe Hua Hin, Chang Wat Prachuap Khiri Khan 77110, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[6, 23, "Plot"], [1, 5, "Plot"], [24, 30, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [31, 39, "SubDistrict"], [41, 47, "DistrictKeyword"], [48, 55, "District"], [57, 66, "ProvinceKeyword"], [67, 86, "Province"], [87, 92, "PostCode"], [94, 102, "Country"]]}
{"id": 3, "text": "\"1291, 1293 Sutthisan Winitchai Rd, Khwaeng Din Daeng, Khet Din Daeng, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10400, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 11, "HouseNumber"], [12, 31, "Street"], [32, 35, "StreetKeyword"], [36, 43, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [55, 59, "DistrictKeyword"], [60, 70, "DistrictKeyword"], [94, 100, "PostCode"], [44, 54, "SubDistrict"], [101, 109, "Country"], [71, 93, "Province"]]}
{"id": 4, "text": "\"23, 21 ถนน พระราม ๒ Khwaeng Bang Mot, Khet Chom Thong, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10150, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[8, 20, "Street"], [21, 28, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [1, 7, "HouseNumber"], [29, 38, "SubDistrict"], [39, 43, "DistrictKeyword"], [44, 55, "District"], [56, 78, "Province"], [79, 85, "PostCode"], [86, 94, "Country"]]}
{"id": 5, "text": "\"Bang Na-Trat Frontage Rd, Khwaeng Bang Na, Khet Bang Na, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10260, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 22, "Street"], [23, 26, "StreetKeyword"], [27, 34, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [35, 43, "SubDistrict"], [44, 48, "DistrictKeyword"], [49, 57, "District"], [58, 80, "Province"], [81, 87, "Plot"], [88, 96, "Country"]]}
{"id": 6, "text": "\"Florida, USA\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 9, "City"], [10, 13, "Country"]]}
{"id": 7, "text": "\"Thapae Rd, Amphoe Mueang Chiang Mai, Chang Wat Chiang Mai 50300, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 7, "Street"], [8, 11, "StreetKeyword"], [12, 18, "DistrictKeyword"], [19, 37, "District"], [38, 47, "ProvinceKeyword"], [48, 58, "Province"], [59, 65, "PostCode"], [66, 74, "Country"]]}
{"id": 8, "text": "\"Bangkok, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 9, "City"], [10, 18, "Country"]]}
{"id": 9, "text": "\"31/3 Beach, Ao Nang, Krabi, 81180, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 5, "HouseNumber"], [6, 12, "Street"], [13, 21, "City"], [22, 28, "Province"], [29, 35, "PostCode"], [36, 44, "Country"]]}
{"id": 10, "text": "\"Mueang Suphan Buri District, Suphan Buri, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 19, "District"], [20, 29, "DistrictKeyword"], [30, 42, "Province"], [43, 51, "Country"]]}
{"id": 11, "text": "\"Mueang Suphan Buri District, Suphan Buri, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 19, "District"], [20, 29, "DistrictKeyword"], [30, 42, "Province"], [43, 51, "Country"]]}
{"id": 12, "text": "\"Mueang Suphan Buri District, Suphan Buri, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": []}
{"id": 13, "text": "\"1 ซอย 20 ถนน สุขุมวิท Khwaeng Khlong Toei, Khet Khlong Toei, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10110, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 2, "HouseNumber"], [3, 22, "Street"], [23, 30, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [31, 43, "District"], [44, 48, "DistrictKeyword"], [49, 61, "District"], [62, 84, "Province"], [85, 91, "PostCode"], [92, 100, "Country"]]}
{"id": 14, "text": "\"Ekkamai Rd, Phra Khanong Nuea, Khet Watthana, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10110, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 8, "Street"], [9, 12, "StreetKeyword"], [13, 31, "District"], [32, 36, "DistrictKeyword"], [37, 46, "District"], [47, 69, "Province"], [70, 76, "PostCode"], [77, 85, "Country"]]}
{"id": 15, "text": "\"587, 589 , 589/7-9 Fashion Island Thanon Ram Intra, Khan Na Yao, Bangkok 10230, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 19, "HouseNumber"], [20, 52, "Street"], [53, 65, "District"], [66, 73, "Province"], [74, 80, "PostCode"], [81, 89, "Country"]]}
{"id": 16, "text": "\"Nong Prue, Pattaya City, Bang Lamung District, Chon Buri 20150, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": []}
{"id": 17, "text": "\"76/1 Maharaj Rd, Tambon Pak Nam, Amphoe Mueang Krabi, Chang Wat Krabi 81000, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 5, "HouseNumber"], [6, 13, "Street"], [14, 17, "StreetKeyword"], [18, 24, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [25, 33, "SubDistrict"], [34, 40, "DistrictKeyword"], [41, 54, "District"], [55, 64, "ProvinceKeyword"], [65, 70, "Province"], [71, 77, "PostCode"], [78, 86, "Country"]]}
{"id": 18, "text": "\"622 Emporium Tower 23rd Floor, Sukhumvit 24 Road, Klongton, Klongtoey, Bangkok 10110, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 4, "HouseNumber"], [5, 50, "Street"], [51, 71, "SubDistrict"], [72, 79, "Province"], [80, 86, "PostCode"], [87, 95, "Country"]]}
{"id": 19, "text": "\"Lam Luk Ka District, Pathum Thani, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 11, "District"], [12, 21, "DistrictKeyword"], [22, 35, "Province"], [36, 44, "Country"]]}
{"id": 20, "text": "\"Samut Prakan, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 14, "Province"], [15, 23, "Country"]]}
{"id": 21, "text": "\"607 Phet Kasem Rd, Khwaeng Bang Wa, Khet Phasi Charoen, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10160, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 4, "HouseNumber"], [5, 15, "Street"], [16, 19, "StreetKeyword"], [20, 27, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [28, 36, "SubDistrict"], [37, 41, "DistrictKeyword"], [42, 56, "District"], [57, 79, "Province"], [80, 86, "PostCode"], [87, 95, "Country"]]}
{"id": 22, "text": "\"4th Floor , Central Chidlom 1027 Phloen Chit Rd, Lumphini, Pathum Wan District, Bangkok 10331, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 45, "Street"], [46, 49, "StreetKeyword"], [50, 59, "SubDistrict"], [60, 70, "District"], [71, 80, "DistrictKeyword"], [81, 88, "Province"], [89, 95, "PostCode"], [96, 104, "Country"]]}
{"id": 23, "text": "\"233 S Sathon Rd, Khwaeng Yan Nawa, Khet Sathon, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10120, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 6, "HouseNumber"], [7, 17, "Street"], [18, 25, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [26, 35, "SubDistrict"], [36, 40, "DistrictKeyword"], [41, 48, "District"], [49, 71, "Province"], [72, 78, "PostCode"], [79, 87, "Country"]]}
{"id": 24, "text": "\"Pa Tong, Kathu District, Phuket 83150, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 9, "City"], [10, 15, "District"], [16, 25, "DistrictKeyword"], [26, 32, "Province"], [33, 39, "PostCode"], [40, 48, "Country"]]}
{"id": 25, "text": "\"622 Sukhumvit Rd, Khwaeng Khlong Tan, Khet Khlong Toei, Krung Thep Maha Nakhon 10110, Thailand\"", "meta": {}, "annotation_approver": null, "labels": [[1, 4, "HouseNumber"], [5, 14, "Street"], [15, 18, "StreetKeyword"], [19, 26, "SubDistrictKeyword"], [27, 38, "SubDistrict"], [39, 43, "DistrictKeyword"], [44, 56, "District"], [57, 79, "Province"], [80, 86, "PostCode"], [87, 95, "Country"]]}
```

I need to parse this file and provide a list of lists as the output.
Output:

> [('ซอยหมู่บ้านหนองแก', 'Plot'), ('8', 'Plot'), ('/', 'Plot'), ('89', 'Plot'), ('Tambon', 'SubDistrictKeyword'), ('Nong',
>   'SubDistrict'), ('Kae', 'SubDistrict'), ('Amphoe', 'DistrictKeyword'),
>   ('Hua', 'District'), ('Hin', 'District'), ('Chang',
>   'ProvinceKeyword'), ('Wat', 'ProvinceKeyword'), ('Prachuap',
>   'Province'), ('Khiri', 'Province'), ('Khan', 'Province'), ('77110',
>   'PostCode'), ('Thailand', 'Country')]

Each tuple consists of a “token” - “label” pair. The tokens are a substring of the text contained in the dict and the indices to begin and end the substring are mentioned in the “labels” key.

I tried :

```
import json
data=json.load('sample_json')
```

However, i get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

I think it is because of the non-latin characters however I can't find anything to solve it

Comment: It looks like your file is not valid json. Try using the validator at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: You're right. The jsonlint showed that the file was invalid. Because there were multiple lines in the json file. 

This worked:
    `import pandas as pd
    p1=pd.read_json('sample_json.json', encoding='utf-8',lines=True)
    print(p1)`
But the non- latin characters are still not being read (they are getting parsed as NaN)

Comment: Why are you trying to read an invalid json file with pandas or anything else?
Fix it first, then it could be successfully loaded using the code in my answer with all of the characters.
Just wrap the entire file in square brackets and add a comma after each object.

Answer (score 0):

If `sample_json` is a `str` and not a `file` handle, then you need `json.loads` not `json.load` (notice the s, for `string`(or at least that's how I remember the difference))

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open the file first:

```
In [1]: import json                                                             
In [2]: f = open("sample_json")                                                 
In [3]: data = json.load(f)                                                     
In [4]: data                                                                    
Out[4]: 
{'id': 2,
 'text': '"8/89 ซอยหมู่บ้านหนองแก Tambon Nong Kae, Amphoe Hua Hin, Chang Wat Prachuap Khiri Khan 77110, Thailand"',
 'meta': {},
 'annotation_approver': None,
 'labels': [[6, 23, 'Plot'],
  [1, 5, 'Plot'],
  [24, 30, 'SubDistrictKeyword'],
  [31, 39, 'SubDistrict'],
  [41, 47, 'DistrictKeyword'],
  [48, 55, 'District'],
  [57, 66, 'ProvinceKeyword'],
  [67, 86, 'Province'],
  [87, 92, 'PostCode'],
  [94, 102, 'Country']]}
```

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 272: character maps to <undefined>

This is the error it is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `json.load` accepts a file stream, not str. You have to either use `json.loads` instead, or pass an opened file as a parameter.
You also need to specify the encoding to read non-ascii symbols.

```py
with open('test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: I tried this. Now it shows: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 196)
Note: I edited the original question to include all the data in the JSON file.